# "Once you do something" or "once you have done something"?

Tags: tense, subordinate-clauses

Tell me please if there is any difference between the following sentences.

> 1. Once you do the task, you can go on to the next one.
> 2. Once you have done the task, you can go on the next one.

Could the first mean that as soon as someone begin to do the task he can go on to the next one?

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. Do you have a source for this? Maybe you made a mistake while posting the question.

Comment: I have seen it being used in similar contexrts. For example: "once you get to know it, it is not very hard.""

Comment: That's not what I meant. ' _Once you do your **the** task..._' - There is an unwanted '***the***' in that sentence, that's making it invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Both sentences are incorrect. I have corrected them out for you:

> 1. Once you do your task, you can go on to the next one.
> 2. Once you have done the task, you can go on to the next one.

Both of these sentences are correct, if I'm not wrong. They mean the same thing too, with the only difference being the tenses. Notably, '*have done*' falls under '***present perfect tense***'.

Comment: Why is "your" better than "the" in this case (1)? Your sentence 2 is identical to the original sentence 2. And you claim that the original is wrong and that yours is correct.